# Multiply every matrix of a numpy array with the transpose of every other efficiently

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Given a numpy array `M` I want to calculate the matrix product `M[i] @ M[j].T` of every 2-combination of matrices of this array. After having applied some operations to that matrix (the product), I want to store the results in another matrix at position `[i,j]`. Is there a way to compute this fast without iterating over two nested loops?

I.e. what I want to avoid (because it takes literally hours) is:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.rand(7000,3,3)
r = np.zeros((len(M), len(M)))

for i in range(len(r)):
    for j in range(len(r[0])):
        n = M[i] @ M[j].T
        r[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(n)
```

Comment: What about `v.idx()`?

Comment: We are iterating over vertices and `v.idx()` denotes the corresponding index.

Comment: this would be much easier if you generated some sample data so the results can be checked

Comment: @yatu Okay, I changed the code snippet to an equivalent problem.

Comment: What is `r`'s shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You wanted `r`'s shape to be `(M.shape[0],M.shape[0])`.

```
M = np.random.rand(700,3,3)
t = M.shape[0]
r = np.zeros((t, t))
```

This is equivalent to the first statement of your inner loop

```
q = M[:,None,...] @ M.swapaxes(1,2)
```

And this completes the inner/outer loop

```
p = np.linalg.norm(q, axis=(2,3))
```

---

```
for i in range(len(r)):
    for j in range(len(r[0])):
        n = M[i] @ M[j].T
        r[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(n)

>>> np.all(np.isclose(p,r))
True
```

---

With `M.shape -> (70,3,3)` it is about 42 times faster than the for loop.
With `M.shape -> (700,3,3)` it is about 36 times faster than the for loop.
My poor computer cannot handle `M.shape --> (7000,3,3)` ... `MemoryError`.

Comment: Oops, I didn‘t notice the errors when renaming my variables. Nevertheless, you still understood it the way I had intended it to be understood. Thank you so much :)